# error: command LOGIN illegal in state AUTH, only allowed in states NONAUTH, how to solve it?

Tags: python-3.x

Why can't I login to an imap server in python? The exception that occurred is “command LOGIN illegal in state AUTH, only allowed in states NONAUTH”.

Someone told me that I used to login without logout，but I don't know how to solve it!

```
 try_connect_mail_host(self.imap4_ssl.login, self.user, self.password)

def try_connect_mail_host(func, *args):
    if len(args) != 2:
        raise RuntimeError()
    retry_times = 0
    while 1:
        if retry_times == 10:
            func(args[0], args[1])
        else:
            try:
                func(args[0], args[1])
                break
            except IMAP4.error as e:
                retry_times += 1
                LOGGER.error(e)
                time.sleep(10)
```